Understanding Gibbs free energy and alternative explanations of the equation
I wanted to verify that my understanding of Gibbs energy was correct. Since I have a habit of explaining things through different perspectives, I thought of an alternative interpretation of Gibbs' free energy to the $S_{univ}=S_{sys}+S_{surr}$, which I am not sure is entirely accurate. Based on the definition that $\Delta S = \frac{q_{rev}}{T}$, $$\Delta G=\Delta H-q_{rev}$$ Under constant pressure, $\Delta H=q$ and $\Delta G$ becomes, $$\Delta G = q-q_{rev}$$ Since $q_{rev}$ is the heat transferred under reversible conditions and $\Delta U=q + w$, $q_{rev}$ is the minimum amount of heat transferred when the reaction occurs reversibly and is the heat transferred generating net zero entropy. Hence $\Delta G$ is the difference between the reversible heat transferred and the actual heat transferred which measures how much the reaction deviates from reversiblity quantitatively. When $\Delta G$ is positive, heat is required from the surroundings and hence is not spontaneous, whereas when $\Delta G$ is negative, energy is released into the surroundings and $\Delta G$ is the maximum energy available from the reaction.


[OP] Based on the definition that $\Delta S = \frac{q_{rev}}{T}$,

You have to be careful with the subscripts. This should read
$$\Delta S_\mathrm{surr} = \frac{q_{rev}}{T}$$

[OP] $\Delta G=\Delta H-q_{rev}$

should have subscripts as well:
$$\Delta G_\mathrm{surr}=\Delta H_\mathrm{surr}-q_{rev}$$
This is not the $\Delta G$ you are usually interested in. Instead, you need to start with
$$\Delta G_\mathrm{sys}=\Delta H_\mathrm{sys}- T \Delta S_\mathrm{sys}$$
$\Delta H_\mathrm{sys}$ and $\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}$ are independent of each other. $\Delta H_\mathrm{sys}$ and $\Delta S_\mathrm{surr}$ are related, but that does not allow you to calculate $\Delta G_\mathrm{sys}$, you also need the value of $\Delta S_\mathrm{sys}$.

[OP] Hence ΔG is the difference between the reversible heat transferred and the actual heat transferred which measures how much the reaction deviates from reversiblity quantitatively.

This is not the case because the assumptions above are incorrect.

Thank you for your answer and correction, I have always thought that $\Delta S_{sys} = \frac{q_{rev}}{T}$ which is a pretty significant misconception around Gibbs Energy.

@AlexZhao You are right. Since the change in entropy of the universe is zero (for a reversible process), $\Delta S_\mathrm{surr} = -\frac{q_{rev}}{T}$ and $\Delta S_\mathrm{sys} = \frac{q_{rev}}{T}$.

The way I look at this is that $\Delta G$ is just entropy accounting. You want the entropy change of the universe to be positive, but while tracking the entropy of your system might be relatively straightforward (though not trivial), tracking the entropy change of the universe is less so.
However, if you know the entropy change of the system, then the entropy change of the universe is just the sum of the system entropy change and the entropy change in the surroundings.
We're tracking the entropy change in the surrounding via $\Delta H$ (see relation between $q$ and $\Delta S$). The factor of $T$ has been multipled through so that it shows up as $T\Delta S$. The reason it is $\Delta H$ and not $\Delta U$ or $q$ is that most of our chemistry takes place in environments that are much closer to constant pressure, so we use enthalpy to account for the pressure-volume work.
So, the rough accounting is:
$$\underset{-\Delta S_{univ}}{\underbrace{\Delta G}} = \underset{-\Delta S_{surr}}{\underbrace{\Delta H}} - \underset{\Delta S_{sys}}{\underbrace{T\Delta S}}$$
Note the change in sign. So while positive changes in entropy associate with sponaneity, negative $\Delta G$ is associated with spontaneity.

What Alex Zhao states in his last line is nearly correct. The last sentence should just be modified so that : $\Delta G$ is the maximum amount of non thermic energy available from the reaction. For example, this energy may be emitted as electricity in a galvanic cell, according to the following equation : $$\Delta G = - zEF$$ where $z$ is the number of electrons appeared in the redox equation, $E$ is the theoretical emf or tension of the cell, and $F$ is the Faraday (about $96500$ Cb).

Yep, and there is a related state function called the availability or exergy which would be the maximum amount of non-thermic energy at system temperature $T$ PLUS thermic energy in changing system temperature from $T$ to that of a cool reservoir at $T_R$.  It doesn't get used much in chemistry, but in practical applications where you assume the environment is a fixed temperature it can come in handy.

Very little of the last sentence in the original post is correct. You can run a reaction reversibly, and $\Delta G$ could be positive, zero or negative (like charging or discharging a battery). Whether a reaction is exothermic or endothermic is not directly correlated to the Gibbs energy of reaction.
